# Radial gradient draw performance - Can OpenGL-ES improve?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios4, ios

I'm working on a image manipulation app that overlays a radial gradient over an image loaded from the photo library.

On screen I have a slider to dynamically in/decrease the radius of the radial gradient. I've found the performance on the simulator to be just fine, but on an iPhone 3G or 3GS it is *much* slower to redraw when moving the slider.

I'm currently using `CGContextDrawRadialGradient` for drawing. The steps I'm following for every redraw:

1. Create the graphics context: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)`;
2. Create gradient object: `CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents`
3. Draw the image (photo loaded from photo library) to the scale of the screen: `drawInRect`
4. Set to an overlay blend mode: `CGContextSetBlendMode`
5. Draw the gradient: `CGContextDrawRadialGradient`
6. Create a UIimage from using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
7. `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`
8. Draw the completed image to screen: `drawInRect`.

Is there a faster way to draw? Perhaps using OpenGL?

Any suggestions/sample code would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas that might improve performance
(assuming you're using the gradient to add vignetting to the image):

- **cache your image drawing** in a `CGLayer` that has the same size as the view, **this avoids scaling** each time you need to draw it.
- **cache the drawing of the radial gradient** into another `CGLayer`.
- when you **need to show the result**:

  - draw the image layer
  - followed by the overlay blend setting
  - followed by the gradient layer
  - all into the drawing context of the view.
- when the **user moves the slider**, you can either:

  - **redraw the gradient layer** then the composition.
  - **redraw the composition** while scaling the gradient layer, and when the use lifts his finger off the slider redraw the gradient layer then composite again.

Comment: Excellent. Let me give that a try. Thanks.