# drawRect: speed and CGContextDrawRadialGradient (super slow?)

Tags: ios, core-graphics, drawrect, gradient

I'm having problems with my `UIView` subclass' `drawRect:` function.
I use `CGContextDrawRadialGradient()` in it, and it.
When the user drags my UIView it struggled to keep up if I include the gradient.

Using Time Profiler I see that literally > 98% of my time is spent in my subclass' `drawRect`: method.

First: would using a static image of a gradient be faster?
Second: is there any way to speed this up? Can I cache the gradient somehow? it doesn't change much but paths around it and intersecting it do change as you drag the `UIView`.

If anybody knows of a general guide on how to make `drawRect:` methods not suck up all the cpu cycles, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. One solution is to draw a smaller gradient and scale it up. The results is not pixel perfect, but faster.

See also the ideas mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912236/radial-gradient-draw-performance-can-opengl-es-improve/3994234#3994234).